# how can I put template into volume deployment attribute

Tags: kubernetes-helm, quarkus

Following the [documentation](https://docs.quarkiverse.io/quarkus-helm/dev/index.html), I couldn't get it to work.
I need to put the model in the volume deployment attribute.

What I can did understand, that helm can't get reference volume deployment attribute.
I did this...

```
quarkus.helm.expressions."volumes".path=spec.template.spec.volumes
quarkus.helm.expressions."volumes".expression={{- include "deployment.volumes" . }}
```

And I expect this

```
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  ...
  template:
  ...
  spec:
    volumes: {{- include "deployment.volumes" . }}
```

Please, can some help me? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it!!!

```
{{- define "volumeMounts" -}}
  volumeMounts:
{{- end }}

{{- define "volumes" -}}
  volumes:
{{- end }}

{{- define "deployment.volumeMounts" -}}
{{- include "volumeMounts" . | nindent 10 }}
{{- include "volumes" . | nindent 8 }}
{{- end }}

quarkus.helm.expressions."deployment.volumeMounts".path=spec.template.spec.containers.volumeMounts
quarkus.helm.expressions."deployment.volumeMounts".expression={{ include "deployment.volumeMounts" . }}
```

As the volumeMounts attribute is the last to be defined in the template, I linked what I wanted through it.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**